# Simulate click on tab Bootstrap, JavaScript, Html5

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working with bootstrap, php, html5 and javascript.

I want to active the following javascript code without clicking on the tab "#mymap".
So I want to simulate a click there.

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#mymap"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: {lat: 48.614399, lng: 21.616646},
        scrollwheel: true,
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
     });

});
```

How can I create a javascript function to do that and call it from the PHP code? Or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That *is* a Javascript function to do that.

Change it to this:

```
var doClickFunct = function(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {lat: 48.614399, lng: 21.616646},
    scrollwheel: true,
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#mymap"]').on('shown.bs.tab', doClickFunct});
```

Then whenever you want to execute it just call `doClickFunct()`

Comment: It sounds good, but how can I call that function from the HTML code?

Comment: i told you. `doClickFunct()`

Comment: obviously, you put it in script tags. `<script>doClickFunct();</script>`

Comment: It works if I add a button like this:

    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doClickFunct();" />

But it is not working if I just call     <script>doClickFunct();</script>, what is what I want.

Comment: put it in the head, not the body. or just change the `var doClickFunct = function(){` to `function doClickFunct(){`

Comment: I changed the var but still not working... :(
I need the call in the body, but I tried to put it in the head, just for try, and it doesn't work.